# Execute java class from panel izpack

Tags: java, izpack

I new to izpack. I have all the panels and a java class which takes mongodb collection and produces excel as output.I want to run this java code and produce excel when i click next on a particular panel. How can I achieve that??

Comment: What version of izpack do you use?

Comment: Currently i'm using 5.0

Answer (score 2):

[Short version](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/IZPACK/Executing+a+Java+Class+with+ProcessPanel):

**First**

Make your Java classes and package it into a JAR. Example:

```
package org.callimachusproject;
import com.izforge.izpack.panels.process.AbstractUIProcessHandler;

public class HelloWorld {
  public void run(AbstractUIProcessHandler handler, String[] args) {
    handler.logOutput("Hello, World!", false);
  }
}
```

**Second**

Set up the install.xml file: add `<resource>` entry, reference your jar, use a ProcessPanel to execute your Java class.

```
<installation>
  <resources>
    <res id="ProcessPanel.Spec.xml" src="installer/ProcessPanel.Spec.xml"/>
  </resources>
  <jar src="path/to/hello.jar" stage="install"/>
  <jar src="path/to/mongodb.jar" stage="install"/>
  <jar src="path/to/other.jar" stage="install"/>
 <panels>
   <panel classname="ProcessPanel"/>
 </panels>
</installation>
```

**Third**

Create the ProcessPanel.Spec.xml file

```
<processing>
  <logfiledir>$INSTALL_PATH</logfiledir>
  <job name="setup">
    <executeclass name="org.callimachusproject.HelloWorld">
        <arg>${someVariable}</arg>
    </executeclass>
  </job>
  <onFail previous="true" next="false" />
  <onSuccess previous="false" next="true" />
</processing>
```

For further reading, you will find [izpack doc](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/IZPACK/Executing+a+Java+Class+with+ProcessPanel) useful.